# How to extract longest possible words from a string in python

Tags: python

I have a python programme as follows.

```
output = []
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence_tokens = []
    for item in selected_concepts:
        index = sentence.find(item)
        if index >= 0:
             sentence_tokens.append((index, item))
    sentence_tokens = [e[1] for e in sorted(sentence_tokens, key=lambda x: x[0])]
    output.append(sentence_tokens)
```

Given the `sentences` and `selected_concepts` I need to extract **word-level** longest concept matches from `selected_concepts` in the order of the sentence. Both `sentences` and `selected_concepts` are preprocessed, so they do not contain any punctuations marks, additional

For example;

```
sentences = ["i love data mining and machine learning", "python is the best programming language", "the learning process of data mining and python are awesome"]

selected_concepts = ["learning", "python", "programming language", "d", "dat", "data", "data mining", "a m", "machine learning", "l"]
```

Current Output:

```
[['l', 'd', 'dat', 'data', 'data mining', 'a m', 'machine learning', 'learning'], ['python', 'programming language', 'l'], ['learning', 'l', 'd', 'dat', 'data', 'data mining', 'a m', 'python']]
```

I want the output to be;

```
[["data mining", "machine learning"], ["python", "programming language"], ["learning", "data mining", "python"]]
```

The issue in my current programme is that it fails to distinguish the overlapping concepts such as `d`, `dat`, `data` and `data mining` and to obtain only `data mining` as the output.

I am not interested in using regex patterns as it slowed down the process.

Please let me know if any further details are needed.

Comment: regex doesnt slow the proecess in fact a powerful way to find patterns..

Comment: Why do your output have two values instead of one(longest)?

Comment: @DecaK what I meant by longest is  in the instances such as `d`, `dat`, `data` and `data mining`. The longest is the `data mining`. I hope it is clear now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you don't want to include any 'concepts' that are also part of a longer 'concept' you're already finding?

Regex can actually be very efficient and may prove faster than the solution you wrote. However, your solution as you shared can be fixed by simply adding the line:

```
output = [[w1 for w1 in l if not any([w2 != w1 and w2.find(w1) >= 0 for w2 in l])] for l in output]
```

That's not very efficient though, since it will still find all the solutions and then run a fairly costly operation to remove all of the duplicates that were included in longer results.

Only sorting the list by length (using regex or otherwise) won't work, since sub-strings may be part of multiple longer strings and should still be found if they are found outside those longer strings. For example, if `selected_concepts` is something like `["big example", "small example", "example", "small", "big"]`. Then running for sentence `"this big example has a small solution for example"` should still find `["big example", "small", "example"]`.

However, your code has some more problems, since it ignores your requirement that you're only looking for whole word concepts. In your example, if you add `"v"` as a concept, it would be found (in `love`) and it would not be eliminated as part of another concept. Also, concepts that appear both by themselves and as part of a larger concept are eliminated by the line I provided.

A somewhat better, more complete solution (still without regex):

```
sentences = ["i love data mining and machine learning", "python is the best programming language",
             "the learning process of data mining and python are awesome"]
selected_concepts = ["learning", "python", "programming language", "d", "dat", "data", "data mining", "a m",
                     "machine learning", "l"]

split_sentences = [s.split() for s in sentences]
split_selected_concepts = [s.split() for s in sorted(selected_concepts, key=len, reverse=True)]

sentence_concepts = []
for s in split_sentences:
    concepts = []
    for c in split_selected_concepts:
        new_s = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(s):
            # if concept is found
            if s[i:i + len(c)] == c:
                # save it and skip it, so it isn't found again
                concepts.append((i, c))
                # keep blanks in new_s to ensure correct index for further results
                new_s.extend(len(c) * [None])
                i += len(c)
            else:
                # if the current word doesn't start this concept, keep it
                new_s.append(s[i])
                i += 1
        s = new_s
    # reorder the found concepts and turn the lists back into strings
    sentence_concepts.append([' '.join(x[1]) for x in sorted(concepts, key=lambda x: x[0])])

print(sentence_concepts)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. However, I am wondering why it gives results that are not in correct order for the following sentence and concepts. Do you have any idea to fix it? Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: sentences = ["viscosity behaviour and persistence length of sodium xanthan in aqueous sodium chloride zero shear rate intrinsic viscosities eta of sodium xanthan in aqueous nacl at 25 degrees c were determined for five samples ranging in weight average molecular weight from 2 x 10 5 to 4 x 10 6 at salt concentrations cs between 0 005 and 1 m at which the polysaccharide maintains its double helical structure"]

Comment: selected_concepts = ['viscosity', 'shear rate', 'length', 'weight', 'intrinsic', 'cs', 'xanthan', 'determined', 'nacl', 'rate', 'degrees c', 'polysaccharide', 'viscosities', 'zero', 'sodium chloride', 'helical', 'salt', 'persistence length', 'behaviour', 'concentrations', 'eta', 'average', 'shear', 'sodium', 'molecular weight', 'double helical', 'persistence', 'samples', 'molecular', 'double', 'chloride', 'degrees', 'structure', 'weight average molecular weight', 'aqueous', 'ranging']

Comment: Because there was a bug in it, as it turns out - sorry about that. It was collecting the index where it found a concept in the remaining text, but as it was removing the previously found concepts from the remaining text to avoid duplicate finds, that index wasn't entirely correct. I've fixed the code by adding `new_s.extend(len(c) * [None])` and updated the answer. The new solution inserts blanks, to maintain the correct index.

Answer (score 3):

Regex works here.  First, sort your list of concepts descending by length before turning it into a regular expression, since the `re` module doesn't support overlapping matches.  Then when you use `re.findall`, the longest words will always be matched first.

---

```
import re

r = sorted(selected_concepts, key=len, reverse=True)
rgx = '|'.join([fr'\b{word}\b' for word in r])

[re.findall(rgx, sentence) for sentence in sentences]
```

```
[['data mining', 'machine learning'],
 ['python', 'programming language'],
 ['learning', 'data mining', 'python']]
```

Comment: This solution works somewhat for the specific data provided, but it fails when the sentences contain multiple instances of the concepts and if the concepts partially overlap. For example, if `selected_concepts` is something like `["big example", "small example", "example", "small", "big"]`. Then running for sentence `"this big example has a small solution for example"` should still find `["big example", "small", "example"]`.

Comment: @Grismar concepts partially overlapping is a completely different question, and much more complex.  This solution satisfies the requirements of the question for the example you gave.

Comment: I figured it mattered, as it is implied by the example given by the OP, where phrases also partially overlap; however, I see your point - I just wanted to point out the limitations of this solution for people considering to use it. The solution I provided is only moderately more complex and does not have this issue - but for someone without that requirement, your solution is certainly more succinct.